# How to add border in a image with clip-path: circle() property in css

Tags: html, css, image, border, clip-path

I want to know how to add border in image clip-path:circle(); any alternative way to add border?

like : border:5px solid red;

I tried this:

```css
.roundedimage {
  width: 200px;
  clip-path: circle();
}
```

```html
<img src="images/tv.jpg" alt="rounded Image" class="roundedimage">
```

How to proceed next because border-radius is not working

Comment: You need to explain in what way `border-radius` "*isn't working*."

Answer (score 0):

`border-radius` works on an image. See below example. Is there something else you were looking for?

```css
.roundedimage {
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius:100vh;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200" alt="rounded Image" class="roundedimage">
```